# Как VS code поменять цвет шрифта, мне не нужно менять всю тему, а только цвет переменных?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Если в самой теме то не понятно где там

Comment: Это шутка или вы вопроса не поняли?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-personalize-the-ide?view=vs-2019

Comment: На следующий раз задавайте вопрос в описание, а не в краткой форме!